# Issue with iOS Build in Flutter Project .../Flutter/Debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "Runner" in project "Runner")

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios

I am working on a Flutter project. Declared few dependencies in the pubspec.yaml file. Project is building fine on Android, but when I try to run on iOS. I am getting the below error. Searched multiple issues, couldn't figure out the exact issue.

```
.../Flutter/Debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "Runner" in project "Runner") (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

pubspec.yaml dependencies

```
flutter_svg: ^0.19.1
flutter:
  sdk: flutter
flutter_dash: ^0.0.1
readmore: ^1.0.1
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
chopper: ^3.0.6
logging: ^0.11.4
package_info: '>=0.4.3+2 <2.0.0'
provider: ^4.3.2+3
sprintf: ^5.0.0
```

Comment: Did you run `pod install` in your IOs project?

Comment: try cleaning derived data : File > Workspace settings > Click the circled gray arrow icon > move to trash the "Derived data" folder > clean & build. 
Install your pods.
Hope this might help!

Comment: @SnehalLokhande Did that. It didn't work. It is showing the same error.

Comment: @Tobi696 yeah i have run that command

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Somehow the `Debug.xcconfig` & `Release.xcconfig` files were missing from `ios/Flutter` directory. I created them and added the following lines.

**Debug.xcconfig** file

```
#include "Generated.xcconfig"
```

**Release.xcconfig** file

```
#include "Generated.xcconfig"
```